# Sharepoint 2007 - checkbox field does not appear in custom list form

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I...
1. created a list in Sharepoint 2007 that has a Yes/No field, which I wish to set with a checkbox.
2. In Sharepoint Designer 2007, I created an .aspx file in my List/Item folder to replace the NewForm.aspx.
3. I inserted a Custom List Form, Sharepoint control.

All the fields are displayed, in both Designer and Sharepoint, except the Yes/No field.

Any clues?
Thanks.